# Call Rest endpoint and display data into Spring MVC table

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this Endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class FileImportsController {

    private EntityImportRequestsService entityImportRequestsService;

    @Autowired
    public FileImportsController(EntityImportRequestsService entityImportRequestsService) {
        this.entityImportRequestsService = entityImportRequestsService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/imported_files")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List<EntityImportRequestsTable> listProducts = entityImportRequestsService.findAll();
        System.out.println("Size is " + listProducts.size());

        model.addAttribute("listProducts", listProducts);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityImportRequests")
public class EntityImportRequestsTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "requestId")
    private String requestId;
}
```

Web page index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Product Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
  <h1>Product List</h1>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <th>requestId</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="product: ${listProducts}">
      <td th:text="${product.requestId}" />
      <td th:text="${product.name}" />
      <td th:text="${product.price}" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page data is not displayed. What is the proper way to call endpoint `imported_files` and display all the data?

Comment: Can you please add the following info, your entity that you want to display ( product maybe? ), the method and the class which returns the entities that you want to display, the whole controller class, the configuration class, and finally please try to visit the url in your browser localhost:8080/applicationname/imported_files, just to confirm that your controller is getting triggered.

Comment: can you share your entityImportRequestsService.findAll method please

Comment: This method implementation is provided by Spring-data-jpa framework: https://www.javaguides.net/2019/07/spring-boot-save-findbyid-findall.html

Comment: I know that Peter i mean the implementation of that method eg.   public List < Employee > findAll() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll(); what you defined of your findAll to return, thats what i am interested

Comment: `List<EntityImportRequestsTable>`

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are trying to display the data in your thymeleaf template with @ RestController annotation instead of @ Controller.